# Java : regex to add space before number

Tags: java, regex

I would like to add a space before each number.

Here : `AS400` would become `AS 4 0 0`

I have tried : `line.replaceAll("[0-9]/g", " "))`

but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
String result = line.replaceAll("\\d", " $0");
```

Or, if you do not want to add a space at the start:

```java
String result = line.replaceAll("(?!^)\\d", " $0");
```

The `\d` pattern matches any digit, and `replaceAll` will match and replace all occurrences, `/g` at the end of the pattern only does harm and needs removing. `(?!^)` means "not at the start of the string".

The `$0` placeholder/replacement backreference in the replacement refers to the whole match value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7FDiSc/1).